# Tensorflow: How to use the "new" Dataset API with QueueRunner

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

Basically I have a list of images to be processed.
And I need to do some pre-processing (data augmentation) after loading, then feed to the main graph of TF.
Currently I am working with a customized generator which takes a list of paths yield a pair of tensors(images) and feed to the network via placeholder. And the sequential processing took ~0.5s for each batch.

I just read the `Dataset` API which I could directly use by using `.from_generator()` function, and I could use the `.get_next()` as input directly.

But how does the `QueueRunner` fit into the framework? Does `Dataset` implicitly utilize `queue` + `dequeue` to maintain its `generator/get_next` pipeline, or it requires me to explicitly feed into a `FIFOQueue` afterwards? If the answer is the later one, what's the best practice to maintain the pipeline to train + validate multiple `random_shuffle` epochs? (I mean, how many `DS/queueRunner` do I need to maintain, and where do I set the shuffle and epochs?)

Comment: For training, I create two datasets: one for training and one for validation. You can set the epochs and shuffle the data with the Dataset API. I never needed to use a QueueRunner.

Comment: I am hoping to utilize the QueueRunner to process data (cpu) and train network (gpu) concurrently to hide the cpu time. It seems Dataset alone can not achieve this, or does it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use the QueueRunner to have queues/buffers if you are using the Dataset API. It is possible to create queues/buffers using the Dataset API and to pre-process data and train a network concurrently. If you have a dataset, you can create a queue/buffer by either using the [prefetch function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#prefetch) or the [shuffle function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shuffle).

See for more information the [official tutorial on the Dataset API](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets).

Here is an example of using a prefetch buffer with pre-processing on the CPU:

```
 NUM_THREADS = 8
 BUFFER_SIZE = 100

 data = ...
 labels = ...
 inputs = (data, labels)

 def pre_processing(data_, labels_):
     with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
         # do some pre-processing here
         return data_, labels_

 dataset_source = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(inputs)
 dataset = dataset_source.map(pre_processing, num_parallel_calls=NUM_THREADS)

 dataset = dataset.repeat(1)  # repeats for one epoch
 dataset = dataset.prefetch(BUFFER_SIZE)

 iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(dataset.output_types,
                                            dataset.output_shapes)
 next_element = iterator.get_next()
 init_op = iterator.make_initializer(dataset)

 with tf.Session() as sess:
     sess.run(init_op)
     while True:
         try:
             sess.run(next_element)
         except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
             break
```